# How can I use redis pipeline in async/await way

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using `StackExchange.Redis` in `Asp.Net Core`. I have done read the chapter '`Pipelining`' in there document.It looks like when I use `db.Wait` then the application will use pipeline to execute the command.But I am not really understood it.
Here is my issue.I have to `hget` many hash-values in my applciation , but the performance of `foreach` is unsatisfactory. I am thinking of use redis pipeline to improve it. But synchronize methods will cause deadlock, so I can't use `db.Wait`.
Can I use redis pipeline in a more native way?

Comment: Have you considered using the FireAndFogrot flag on a synchronous call instead? The ConnectionMultiplexer will take care of any async issues it might have underneath [Source](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/PipelinesMultiplexers)

Comment: @AndrewCui can you post some code? It's hard to understand what are you trying to do and what your problem is.